# Count value from each column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that contains:

```
id datetime country productId
```

Say there are 50 different products, how can I count how many there are for each?

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║  id   ║      datetime       ║ country ║ productId ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ 2012-12-08 14:38:49 ║ us      ║         2 ║
║     2 ║ 2012-12-08 16:38:52 ║ us      ║         2 ║
║     6 ║ 2012-12-08 16:39:50 ║ ca      ║        33 ║
║     7 ║ 2012-12-08 16:54:58 ║ uk      ║         1 ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

This should result in

```
╔═════════╦════════════╗
║ COUNTRY ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║     US  ║          2 ║
║     CA  ║          1 ║
║     UK  ║          1 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╝
```

How can I accomplish this? I've tried counting in the query, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So what's the `COUNT()` for?

Comment: -1 as you did not show any code.

Answer (score 2):

just use `COUNT` aggregate function and grouped them by `COUNTRY`.

```
SELECT COUNTRY, COUNT(*) totalCOUNT
FROM tableName
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY totalCOUNT DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0f48/1)

Comment: thanks! I forgot the group part